# irb --noprompt error with autoindent on

Tags: ruby, irb

I like using the --noprompt option on irb sometimes, especially when I may want to copy code from it and paste it somewhere else.  However, an error occurs when the following appears in the .irbrc file:

```
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT] = true
```

The following error occurs when irb starts up:

```
/Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:280:in `dup': can't dup NilClass (TypeError)
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:280:in `prompt'
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:129:in `block in eval_input'
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:206:in `call'
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:206:in `prompt'
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:220:in `initialize_input'
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/ruby-lex.rb:227:in `each_top_level_statement'
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:155:in `eval_input'
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:70:in `block in start'
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `catch'
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb.rb:69:in `start'
from /Users/keithb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

The error also occurs in JRuby, but the stack trace is of course a bit different.

This is a bug, right?  One would think an inappropriate configuration setting would be handled more gracefully, at minimum reporting the nature of the error at a higher level so the user would have an idea how to resolve it. Or could it be argued that it's the developer's fault for specifying an indent on a nonexistent prompt?

-- Keith

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug.

If you would like to have a `.irbrc` file ignored for special cases (such as when you want `--noprompt`) then you are likely also wanting to supply the `-f` flag to suppress loading your `.irbrc` file.

You will correctly get problems when supplying contradicting options.

TLDR;

`irb -f --noprompt`